# Efficiently access Array.prorotype.filter single-item returns

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am often using `Array.prototype.filter` and I only expect one single element to be truthy.

As filter returns an array of results, I find myself needing to always access that element, so I do something like

```
knownRefundLogics.filter((refundLogic) => this.hasTag(refundLogic.underscoredName))[0]
```

assume that:

```
knownRefundLogics = [{
    "underscoredName": "express_full_refund",
    "camelized": "expressFullRefund"
}, {
    "underscoredName": "express_partial_refund",
    "camelized": "expressPartialRefund"
}, {
    "underscoredName": "express_no_refund",
    "camelized": "expressNoRefund"
}]
```

and `hasTag()` a method that does an `includes()` on an array for the `refundLogic` element.

Is there a more appropriate method to do that, using the spread operator for example?

By the way I know I could potentially split my methods in a way that only a `true` or `false` value is returned but I find that a bit of an overengineered solution.

Comment: `Array.prototype.some()`, `Array.prototype.every()`

Comment: You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), it is guaranteed to return single value

Comment: but would you recommend reduce() for filtering/checking truthiness of values?

Comment: @Andreas is returning true or false, not the actual item..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**Array#find**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function, which returns the first item, which passes the given condition. Also it is more faster that `filter`, because `filter` iterates over all items and then you get only the first one. `find` finds the first matched item and breaks the loop.

From the example you can see, it iterates 2 time instead of 3.

```js
const knownRefundLogics = [{
    "underscoredName": "express_full_refund",
    "camelized": "expressFullRefund"
}, {
    "underscoredName": "express_partial_refund",
    "camelized": "expressPartialRefund"
}, {
    "underscoredName": "express_no_refund",
    "camelized": "expressNoRefund"
}];

const foundItem = knownRefundLogics.find(item => {

   console.log('Iteration');
   
   return item.camelized === 'expressPartialRefund';

});

console.log(foundItem);
```

Comment: the problem with .find is you need to use a polyfill but I'll accept the answer as I didn't specify that in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)() instead - whenever the predicate returns `true`, the the iteration is stopped, and the matching item (not an array) is returned immediately:

```js
const knownRefundLogics = [{"underscoredName":"express_full_refund","camelized":"expressFullRefund"},{"underscoredName":"express_partial_refund","camelized":"expressPartialRefund"},{"underscoredName":"express_no_refund","camelized":"expressNoRefund"}];

const demoHasTag = (t) => t === 'express_partial_refund';

const result = knownRefundLogics.find((refundLogic) => demoHasTag(refundLogic.underscoredName));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution without polyfill, the good old loop is you friend.

```js
var knownRefundLogics = [{
    "underscoredName": "express_full_refund",
    "camelized": "expressFullRefund"
}, {
    "underscoredName": "express_partial_refund",
    "camelized": "expressPartialRefund"
}, {
    "underscoredName": "express_no_refund",
    "camelized": "expressNoRefund"
}];

var selected;
for(var i = 0; i < knownRefundLogics.length; i++){
  let current = knownRefundLogics[i];
  if(current.underscoredName === 'express_partial_refund'){
    selected = current;
    break;
  }
}

console.log(selected);
```

With that you can write your own light polyfill.

```js
function findInArray(array, test){
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(test(array[i], i, array)) return array[i];
  }
}

var knownRefundLogics = [{
    "underscoredName": "express_full_refund",
    "camelized": "expressFullRefund"
}, {
    "underscoredName": "express_partial_refund",
    "camelized": "expressPartialRefund"
}, {
    "underscoredName": "express_no_refund",
    "camelized": "expressNoRefund"
}];

console.log(findInArray(knownRefundLogics, function(item, index, array){
  return item.underscoredName === "express_partial_refund";
}));
```

Comment: or a .forEach I guess? I still didn't hear any opinions in automatically getting the first and only element of a filter function

Comment: No. Unlike a simple loop you can't interrupt the forEach loop.

Comment: For the opinion about filter. It has the same disadvantage than the forEach. It can't be interrupt and it will be forced to walk through the entire array. So if you just need to retrieve the first occurrence that verify your condition, it is not very efficient.